# How to convert column names to multiple rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I've a legacy database containing a table with multiple columns of type boolean. E.g.:

**Table_1**

```
id name           has_lights has_engine has_brakes  has_tyres can_move
1  bullock_cart   false      false      false       true      true
2  car            true       true       true        true      true
3  tank           true       true       true        false     true
```

I'd like to write an SQL query for Table1 to fetch the id and name and the attributes (represented by the name of the column) that are true.

**Expected output:**

```
id name        attributes
-- ----        ----------
1 bullock_cart has_tyres
1 bullock_cart can_move
2 car          has_lights
2 car          has_engine
2 car          has_brakes
2 car          has_tyres
2 car          can_move
3 tank         has_lights
3 tank         has_engine
3 tank         has_brakes
3 tank         can_move
```

I wrote:

```
SELECT id, name,
CASE
  WHEN has_lights THEN 'has_lights'
  WHEN has_engine THEN 'has_engine'
  WHEN has_brakes THEN 'has_brakes'
  WHEN has_tyres THEN 'has_tyres'
  WHEN can_move THEN 'can_move'
END
FROM TABLE1;
```

But this gets me only the 1st matching attribute for each row in Table1 (by virtue of CASE-WHEN).

What is the correct way to retrieve the data in the format I want? Any inputs/help will be greatly appreciated?

Notes:

- The table structure isn't ideal but this is a legacy system and we cannot modify the schema.
- Nested queries are ok as long as they aren't too slow - say for the sample above (I understand the number of matching rows/column factor in the slow-ness).

Answer (score 4):

The simplest method is `union all`:

```
select id, name, 'has_lights' as attribute from t where has_lights union all
select id, name, 'has_engine' from t where has_engine union all
select id, name, 'has_brakes' from t where has_brakes union all
select id, name, 'has_tyres' from t where has_tyres union all
select id, name, 'can_move' from t where can_move;
```

If you have a very large table, then a lateral join is probably more efficient:

```
select t.id, t.name, v.attribute
from t, lateral
     (select attribute
      from (values (has_lights, 'has_lights'),
                   (has_engine, 'has_engine'),
                   (has_brakes, 'has_brakes'),
                   (has_tyres, 'has_tyres'),
                   (can_move, 'can_move')
           ) v(flag, attribute)
      where flag
     ) v;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT name,'has_lights' as attributes FROM YourTable where has_lights = 'TRUE'
UNION ALL
SELECT name,'has_engine' as attributes FROM YourTable where has_engine= 'TRUE'
UNION ALL
SELECT name,'has_brakes' as attributes FROM YourTable where has_brakes = 'TRUE'
UNION ALL
SELECT name,'has_tyres' as attributes FROM YourTable where has_tyres = 'TRUE'
UNION ALL
SELECT name,'can_move' as attributes FROM YourTable where can_move = 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much like the brilliant query [@Gordon posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39390453/939860):

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, v.attribute
FROM   table1 t
JOIN   LATERAL (
   VALUES (has_lights, 'has_lights')
        , (has_engine, 'has_engine')
        , (has_brakes, 'has_brakes')
        , (has_tyres , 'has_tyres')
        , (can_move  , 'can_move')
   ) v(flag, attribute) ON v.flag;
```

Just a bit shorter since the `VALUES` expression can stand on its own.